# Inline blocks inside <button> element

Tags: html, css

```css
button {
  font-size: 0;
}

span {
  font-size: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
    <button>
     <span>Icon</span>
     <span>Text</span>
    </button>
```

In safari property font-size: 0 doesn't kill margin between child inline-block elements. Is it possible to fix it, but not change button tag?

Comment: I think Safari (although you don't mention which version///i assume IOS) has a minimum font size in the setttings,

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few hackish solutions and one that isn't.

Remove space between elements in the markup.

```html
<button>
    <span>Icon</span><span>Text</span>
</button>
```

(another way)

```html
<button>
    <span>Icon</span><
     span>Text</span>
</button>
```

HTML comments

```html
<button>
    <span>Icon</span><!--
    --><span>Text</span>
</button>
```

Or float them and use a clearfix on the button element if you need to use a background color.

```css
button {
    overflow: hidden;
    /* or => http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/ */
}
button > span {
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<button>
     <span>Icon</span>
     <span>Text</span>
</button>
```

You could also use flexbox if you're able to support it.

Answer (score -2):

Please refer both the link this should work out for you.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_letter-spacing
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_text_word-spacing